# how to pass username and password to URL?

Tags: javascript, html, url, web, authentication

I have a login page at work and every day I have to enter user/password.

I want to write something that could help me use variables to improve my work life.
If I inspect the HTML code I find on the user filed:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The field Username is required" id="Username" name="Username" placeholder="Username" value="" type="text">
```

And for the password field:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The field Password is required" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
```

If I fill `value=""` with the username and I then I do the same for the password field I can login! So `value=""` is what I need for both field.

But how to pass this HTML code into the URL? 
My goal is to write a link like `<a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>` that will help me login to that URL in a click with already user/password in it.

Comment: This can't be done without changing the login page. Unless your login page already has a built-in way of receiving login information (which I'm entirely certain it doesn't) you can't pass any useful information in a link. You could certainly try saving the password using your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right @Vishwas Chauhan. If I stick this in a HTML file it works:

```
<form action="http://example.com/" target="_blank" method="post">
<input data-val="true" id="Username" name="Username" value="mybeautifulusername" type="text">
<input data-val="true" id="Password" name="Password" value="mybeautifulpassword" type="password">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="submit" />
</form>
```

but how can I delete the 2 fields and just keep the "submit" button?
I just need the button and not the 2 fields.

Comment: <input type="hidden">

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of extending website is the usage of [GreaseMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)-Scripts.
You could e.g. add a button on page load which injects the credentials into the values of the form fields:

```
window.addEventListener('load', addLoginButton, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the login form has has the **method="GET"** you can pass the variables in the URL. But most certainly the **method="POST"** is the case. In this case there is one fix, you can create a custom webpage which fires an HTTP POST request to the login URL with the required variables set as the username and the password.

You can do this via *PHP using CURL*.